# Как уменьшить размер приложения построенного на Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я создал пустое приложение на **Jetpack Compose**, включил в нем флаг **minifyEnabled = true**  и скомпилировал релизный apk. Его размер оказался **1,7 mb**, что на мой взгляд очень много для пустого приложения.

Можно ли как то уменшить размер приложения? Например можно ли юзать элементы **Text** и **Button** без зависимости androidx.compose.material:material.
И можно ли чтоб androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling не включалась в релизную сборку, ведь это интрумент для отладки?

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-alpha10'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-alpha06'
```

Comment: Это плата за использование фреймворков. На самом деле, 1.7Мб это не так уж и много в наше время. Тут либо смириться, либо писать без фреймворков.

Comment: Можете попробовать включить полную поддержку R8, но на данный момент это не рекомендуется делать
gradle.properties file:
android.enableR8.fullMode=true